# How to erase draw lines i using canvas in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas

In Application i have two buttons in which one button is used as a pencil to draw lines on View and other biutton is used as an eraser to erase lines...?
i am unable erase line plz help?

Comment: there is no direct way to erase lines. You have to keep track of what needs to be drawn and redraw everything when needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below finger paint example code will help you.

You can see the Finger paint example in api demos in android emulator

Api Demos --> Graphics --> Finger Paint

[source link](http://gitorious.org/freebroid/development/blobs/62e92d7a2a3fd2798901ec2e7c452ff0e4067163/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java)

Comment: Ya i have done this thanks.. now i want to undo functionality so i can get back erase lines ...